# Result of initializer not used?

Tags: swift

Why do I get the message below when using the following:

```
MyClass.init(5)
```

Class definition:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {
private static var aNumber = 0

    init(myNumber: Int) {
        MyClass.aNumber = MyNumber
    }
...
}
```

> Result of initializer not used

Comment: Here's the proposal that added the warning to Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0047-nonvoid-warn.md

Comment: Not sure how that relates. init() is a void.

Comment: It’s not void. Init returns a new instance of MyClass

Comment: I see. I can do MyClass(5) as well but it is the same warning. What other technique should I use to avoid the warning?

Comment: `_ = MyClass(5)`, however, that's a design problem. Why would you create an instance which you don't want to use? Why don't you just create a static setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the warning easily, e.g.

```
_ = MyClass(5)
```

However, you have a design problem. Why would you create an instance that you then discard right away?

Instead, make the setter public:

```
static var aNumber = 0
```

and just set

```
MyClass.aNumber = 5
```

or make it a static method:

```
static func setNumber(_ number: Int) {
    aNumber = number
}
```

and call

```
MyClass.setNumber(5)
```